# Firebase Function not returning response to client app

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Running a callable function in firebase. Running it locally in the Firebase emulators. I am returning a simple string just to see if I can get it back to the client, but all I'm getting in the response is `{"data": null}`. I am not entirely sure what the issue here is. I'm sure there is something I do not understand about promises, and if you've helped me on another part of this project through another issue, I appreciate it. Still trying to understand how all of this works. 
Here is the function:

```
exports.createAssetMux = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    console.log('data: ', data)

    admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(data.id).update({
        streamID: '98273498237'
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('update success')
        return {data: 'update successful'}
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('error message: ', error)
        return {data: 'there was an issue updating document'}
    });
});
```

Just trying to get data back to the client at this point. I have had some other issues with Firebase functions that I am trying to work out, and all of this is connected, just didn't want  to over-complicate another post. Any help would be amazing! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return statements are not doing what you expect.  They are just returning a value from the lambda function that you passed to `then` and `catch`.  They are not returning a value from the larger function that you passed to `onCall`.

Callable functions require that you return a promise that resolves with the object you want to send to the client.  Right now, the function passed to `onCall` always returns nothing.  What you will have to do is return the entire promise chain:

```
    return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(data.id).update({
        streamID: '98273498237'
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('update success')
        return {data: 'update successful'}
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('error message: ', error)
        return {data: 'there was an issue updating document'}
    });
```

All I added was a return at the beginning of the first line.

Understanding how JavaScript promises work is crucial to writing effective functions.  I strongly suggest taking some time to learn their usual patterns.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I guess I didn't realize that I had to return the whole thing. Thanks for your help. I am learning a lot about JS  promises working out the kinks in this project. These things make more sense when working them out in a real project, at least for me.  Reading docs helps, but working it out in a project really ties it all together. Thanks again for all your help.